# Spring: Create object with endpoint by id

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently creating a microservice with spring boot and mysql to manage information about auctions. I have created a `Bid`-object and an `Offer`-object. Next to some properties of bid and offers, the most important thing here is the `OneToMany`-Relationship between Offer and Bid, since obviously every offer can have multiple related Bids.

I use the default `JpaRepository`-Interface for my database interactions, and tested my database structure by entering data and testing if I would get the correct output. This all worked fine, but when I tried to test the endpoints of my service that entered the data, I got some curious behaviour. First of all, here's my structure, so you can keep up with what I'm talking about. These are (shortened) versions of my `Bid` and `Offer`-Objects:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Bid {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String bidderUUID;

    @NotNull
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "offerId")
    private Offer offer;

    @NotNull
    private Integer amount;

    private Boolean hasWon;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Offer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String creatorUUID;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer")
    List<Bid> bids;
}
```

This is my very simple repsitory and controller:

```java
public interface BidRepository extends JpaRepository<Bid, Long> {

}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bid")
public class BidController {
    @Autowired
    private BidRepository bidRepository;

    @GetMapping("/bids")
    public List<Bid> getAllBids() {
        return bidRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public void createBid(@RequestBody Bid request) {
        bidRepository.saveAndFlush(request);
    }
}
```

With and offer with the id 27 in the database I proceeded to send a bid to the service.

I'm using postman to test my requests,  and this is what I put in my request body, when adressing the endpoint `localhost:8080/bid/add`:

```json
{
    "amount": 2,
    "bidderUUID": "eine uuid",
    "offerId": 27
}
```

I received a 200 OK response, and thought, seems fine, but the data in the database is wrong, since it looks like this:

[image]

The offer is missing, even though the ID 27 definitely exists. Also, when I'm entering 27 manually and pushing it to the database, the data is correctly recognized.

I think this problem has something to do with the fact, that I expect an `offer`-object when posting the new bid, but only give him the ID, but when I enter the entire object, I get an `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist`.

How can I make spring accept the id of the offer, when transmitting a new bid object?

Answer (score 0):

This happed to me also, so as the solution I added the mapping column as Entity variable. In your case if I say, your `Bid` entity is missing the `offer_id` column mapping, although it mentioned the relationship. Add below entry in your `Bid` table as below:

```
@Column(name = "offer_id")
private Long offerId;
// generate setter-getter
```

Comment: This seems to cause a `DuplicateMappingException` - it doesn't allow me to have duplicate column names. The column does indeed exists, the problem is only that it doesn't get the correct data from the request...

Answer (score 0):

add referencedColumn on the @JoinColumn annotation.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "offerId", referencedColumn = "id")
private Offer offer;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem :C